# How to use cordova-universal-links-plugin in cordova app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need some help understanding if I can use "cordova-universal-links-plugin for the propose action

Basically, a user select a file from dropbox on my browser. Then, I want to redirect to my cordova app with the  selected info. The app is already install on the user device

I was using "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" but it does not work after installing the firebase plugin.. So , I am looking  for an alternative solution

This is the current customURL scheme that used to work with the "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" plugin

```
jobx://jobs/14231709/apply1/upload?downloadUrl=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/view/RESUMEdropbox103.docx&fileName=RESUMEdropbox103.docx&fileSize=13366&sourceName=dropbox
```

My server name is https://mblxxx.home.com/

If I can used the cordova-universal-links-plugin to achieve the same result , would this the correct config?

```
<universal-links>

 <host name="mblxxx.home.com"
    scheme="https"
    path url="*/apply1/upload"
    event="ul_myExampleEvent" />
  </host>
</universal-links>
```